# Decrypt TLS in golang by storing SSL key to be used with Wireshark

Tags: ssl, go, wireshark, tls1.2, nss

I am trying to establish a TLS connection by providing a `tls.Config` struct containing a `Rand` field that should always return the same `int` when calling their `Read` method, cf. the docs here: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config

I've written this builder:

```
func newZeroRand() *rand.Rand {
    return rand.New(rand.NewSource(0))
}
```

And a test to make sure that `rand.Rand` is always returning the same `int` when `Read` is invkoed multiple times, notice the different input params `"foo"` and `"bar"` providing the same output:

```
func TestPredictableZeroRandGenerator(t *testing.T) {
    zeroRand := newZeroRand()
    firstNum, err := zeroRand.Read([]byte("foo"))
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
    secondNum, err := zeroRand.Read([]byte("bar"))
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    // fmt.Printf("firstNum %d secondNum %d \n", firstNum, secondNum)
    if firstNum != secondNum {
        t.Error(fmt.Sprintf("This is not a predictable zero random generator! The first number is: %d the second number is: %d", firstNum, secondNum))
    }
}
```

Using that previously defined `newZeroRand()` I was expecting to generate always the same SSL key inside the file `same-key.log` when providing the TLS configuration like this:

```
func tlsConfig() (*tls.Config, error) {
    w, err := os.OpenFile("same-key.log", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    tlsConfig := tls.Config{
        Rand: newZeroRand(),
        KeyLogWriter: w,
    }
    return &tlsConfig, nil
}
```

But for multiple executions I get different file contents. I may be misunderstanding the details here: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#example_Config_keyLogWriter because when I open those files `same-key.log` after each execution
then I find the structure described here in the NSS Key Log Format from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format

```
CLIENT_RANDOM <FIRST_LONG_ID> <SECOND_LONG_ID>
```

where:

- `<FIRST_LONG_ID>` is always the same
- `<SECOND_LONG_ID>` is changing after each execution **<-- why this is happening?**

When providing a key file `same-key.log` for a batch of packets from a different execution, then **Wireshark is not able to decrpyt** them!

I may be misunderstanding some internals about SSL cryptography here and I was wondering if I should also provide the certificates in the configuration struct? How could I generate these certificates?

Afaik when using certificates on top of the key there should be a piece of information coming from the other side at runtime, so then I can not decrypt the stream of packets if I don't have that information. This is why I thought certificates are not needed if I want to use Wireshark to decrypt those packets.

Otherwise I am not sure how could I force the TCP connection to always encrypt/decrypt the packets with the same key?

**Edit:**

As pointed out by @peter in his answer I was asserting on the length of the input byte slice rather than the actual "deterministic-random value".

I came out with this `Read` implementation for the `tls.Config` struct:

```
type debugRand struct {}
func (dr *debugRand) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for i := range p {
        p[i] = byte(0)
    }
    return len(p), nil
}
func newZeroRand() *debugRand {
    return &debugRand{}
}
```

This is setting to `0` all the elements of the input slice.

However I still generate SSL keys which have different `<SECOND_LONG_ID>` values for different executions.

Is it possible at all to get Wireshark re-using SSL keys **on different TLS connections** when analysing those encrypted TCP packets?

Comment: Did you figure out this or any other way to decrypt the traffic? I am surely missing something trivial or nobody decrypts traffic this way :P

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Read](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) wrong. Your test doesn't test what you think it does. firstNum and secondNum are both 3 because you are reading three random bytes; because you are passing byte slices of length three. You never check the actual random bytes though.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have edited the question providing more details.